# There are at most finitely many primes not dividing any elements in this sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

A perfect number is a natural number $n$ that is the sum of its proper divisors.
Otherwise said, they are the natural numbers $n$ such that
$\sum_{d|n}d=2n.$ For instance, $6$ and $28$ are perfect.

Let $n$ be a perfect number, and for each integer $m\geq1$ define
$a_{m}=-2+\sum_{d|m}d^m.$

I am looking for **hints** to prove the following claim:

> There are at most finitely many primes that do not divide any of the $a_{m}.$

Comment: There are some _really_ weird symbols going on there.

Comment: Geez..... change the title of this post!  Please!

Comment: How is $n$ involved in the definition of $a_m$?

Comment: I have edited your post; hopefully my edits will deter downvoters. I believe what you meant to say in the definition is $$a_{m} = -2+\sum_{d\mid n}d^{m},$$ but I have refrained from putting in this change as I didn't want to substantially edit any of the mathematics.